# Make a Fallout Pipboy from an Rpi

Tags: operating-systems

I want to make a modern [Pipboy](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Pip-Boy) from the Fallout series. But I want to run a Windows OS or Android OS with camera, Bluetooth, gyro, GPS, and SIM card and with a lot of programmable buttons and LEDs. I've never used a RPi so I don't know if it can do all the things that I need.

Comment: You mean like the thing you got with the Fallout 4 Special Edition? A Pipboy with a Holder for your phone and a App that is integrated into the Game?

Comment: Flagging to close. https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-pipboy-3000/overview

Answer (score 26):

Buy yourself a smartphone, you'll get "Android OS with camera, Bluetooth, gyro, GPS, and SIM card and with a lot of programmable buttons and LEDs" -- all already included, working and with plenty of documentation and development environments available.

Comment: And then you can 3D print a Pipboy case for the smartphone. :D

Comment: I agree that this is probably the best option but phones usually don't have "a lot of programmable buttons and LEDs." Granted, neither does the Pi...

Comment: @MichaelMior smartphone screen can be divided into as many LED's as you like, and the touch screen can be as many buttons as you want.

Comment: Also there is a pipboy app for android, it might take the fun out of creating your own interface though.

Comment: You can also buy a PipBoy case. They're low quality, granted, but I don't expect much from a custom print either.

Comment: @lenik True although I assumed the OP was looking for physical LEDs and buttons. If the goal is realism, emulating on a smart phone isn't really the same.

Answer (score 11):

> I want to run a Windows OS or Android OS

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Windows just isn't supported at all on the Pi (only a lesser version called [Windows 10 IoT Core](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot), which isn't much like the regular Windows). Android is [equally problematic](https://howtoraspberrypi.com/install-android-raspberry-pi/); while there are ways to install it, it is noted that:

> No version of Android is officially compatible with the raspberry pi and therefore the version we will install is not optimized for our dear motherboard. It is therefore difficult today to use Android on a daily basis on its raspberry pi [sic] even if the installation we are going to present turns relatively well.

By far the most supported operating systems on the Pi are Linux-based (generally Raspbian is the best bet).

---

There are [HATs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-raspberry-pi-hats/) for things like [4G, GPS, power](https://www.pianywhere.com/) and there is the [Pi Camera Module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/) which might be useful. That said, it may not necessarily be easy to bundle all of that into a convenient package; I would imagine the end product would be a bit heavy and bulky.

If you want some inspiration, take a look at [Project ZeroPhone](https://www.techradar.com/news/project-zerophone-the-ambitious-diy-raspberry-pi-phone), where someone made a phone out of a Pi Zero. However, it was only connected to the 2G network, so probably can't rival modern smartphones.

Comment: More specifically for the Pipboy, I have seen a few great kits available online with what should be fairly easy guides on setting up the Pi for it

Answer (score 5):

You can't run a traditional Windows OS or a usable Android OS on the Pi.

You can run something called Windows IOT which is not a desktop system.

Answer (score 4):

*Note: I don't disagree with other answers, but I think it's a shame no one on raspi.se has attempted to address how you could use a Raspberry Pi to achieve your desired results.*

Although it doesn't meet all of your requirements, Adafruit has a guide for [creating a Pip-Boy](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-pipboy-3000/overview) using a Raspberry Pi. The Pi uses an LCD screen and a Li-Ion battery and runs [a pretty cool Pip-Boy interface](https://github.com/grieve/pypboy) (that is unfortunately written in Python 2).  This was written a while ago and emulates the Pip-Boy 3000 (not Mark IV) from Fallout 3/New Vegas.  This has the notable advantage of not requiring you to place your phone inside a carrier as well as having a hardware dial to switch screens (more realistic).

However, be warned that only one hardware dial is actually wired to the Pi and does anything and there is only one LED that simply lights when the device is powered on (although, I believe that is true to the Pip-Boy).  Unfortunately creating a fully realistic Pip Boy with all the working knobs and dials would be prohibitively expensive for even the most enthusiastic of fans.

Here's a picture of the finished product.

[image: picture of pipboy]